# Display error message at top of form

Tags: php

I'm trying to get the following error to show when some once presses the submit button and has not filled in the required field/s.

Comment: Using "if(isset($_POST['full_name']..." is a bad idea as you'll skip all your validation if no full name has been supplied - use a hidden form field such as <input type="hidden" name="mode" value="update" /> or similar.

Comment: You dont get the error, because you never display it.

Comment: What seems to be the problem, officer?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
require_once("includes/database.php");
require_once("includes/functions.php");

if(isset($_POST['full_name'])) {
    $required = array('full_name','user_name','email','pwd','pwd2');
    $missing = array();
    $validation = array(
        'full_name' => 'Please provide your full name',
        'user_name' => 'Please provide your username',
        'email'     => 'Please provide your valid email address',
        'pwd'     => 'Please provide your password',
        'pwd2'     => 'Please confirm your password',
        'userdup'    => 'Username already registered',
        'emaildup'     => 'Email address already registered',
        'mismatch'     => 'Passwords do not match'
    );

    //Sanitise and clean function
    $full_name = escape($_POST['full_name']);
    $user_name = escape($_POST['user_name']);
    $email = escape($_POST['email']);
    $pwd = escape($_POST['pwd']);
    $pwd2 = escape($_POST['pwd2']);

    foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
        $value = trim($value);
        if(empty($value) && in_array($key,$required)) {
            array_push($missing,$key);
        } else {
            ${$key} = escape($value); //Why exacly do you need to have extra stuff?
        }
    }
    //iterate over the missing elements, and display them
    foreach ($missing as $m){
        echo echo "<strong>Error: </strong>: " . $validation[$m] . "<br>";
    }
    //You need to do some more stuffs, like query the DB to check if the username is a duplicate or not.
}
//...rest of your code ..
```

Comment: Why exacly do you need to have extra stuff?

The extra stuff is the check to make sure the email addres, username is not duplicate in the system and also to compare the two passwords match.

I want to keep the code the same but only get the confirmation message to display if any of the required fields are not filled in.

Is thier a way to get the message to display?